# NodeJS: How to wait for a for-loop of async requests to finish before proceeding with code?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am relatively new to node and trying to create an web app that allows users to get retrieve information from the youtube api by providing a list of youtube channel IDs(already in server) by going to my /retrieve route.

Currently I am looping through an array of objects with channel IDs, and for each ID I use a setTimeOut function to send 1request/500ms (due limitations of the youtube API) and using the request.get request module. I am trying to continue code and res.send AFTER all the requests to youtube is completed. Furtherfore, for each data obj I received from each youtube request, I am parsing and pushing them to the youtubeinfo array.

I have a nodeJS version of v12.16.3.

Here's my code below, sorry for the messiness:

```
router.get('/retrieve', async function(req, res, next) {
  console.log("start")
  const length = datajs.length
  console.log(length);
  var promiseArray = [];
    for(i = 0; i < length; i++){
    promiseArray.push(new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    (function(i){
        setTimeout(function(){
          const channelID = datajs[i]['Channel ID']

          let options = {
              method: 'GET',
              url: url, //url is previously defined

          };
          request.get(url, (err, response, data)=>{
            if (!err) {
        
              parsedData = JSON.parse(data)
              if (parsedData.items){
                // check with retrievede data obj is valid format with items
                const parsedYoutubeobj = {
                "custom_collection": {
                  "title": parsedData.items[0].brandingSettings.channel.title,
                  "body_html": parsedData.items[0].brandingSettings.channel.description,
                  "image": {
                    "src": parsedData.items[0].brandingSettings.image.bannerImageUrl,
                    "alt": "Rails Logo"
                  }
                }
              }
              youtubeinfo.push(parsedYoutubeobj)
              console.log("----------------------")
        
              console.log(parsedYoutubeobj);
              youtubeinfo.push(parsedYoutubeobj);
              resolve(parsedYoutubeobj)
              } else {
                console.log("something is wrong...check if youtube channel still exist")
                reject()
              }
        
            } else{
              console.log("statusCode: "+ response.statusCode)
              console.log("err: "+ err);
              reject(err)
              
            }
          })
      }, 500 * i);
    }(i));
  }))
  }
```

How can I correctly apply promises/async/await to have my code continue after all the async requests are made? I currently creating an array of promises, but it does not seem to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add small piece of code where your for loop ends so basically code will go like this

```
 Promise.all(
    datajs.map((key,item) => {
       return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
          //then your timeout code
       });
    })
  ).then(()=>{console.log('done')})
```

Comment: I have added the code, and moved res.send after then(), but it and console.log("All done", results), never gets executed?

Comment: I have edited the code i think you need to use Promise.all and then loop through your data inside that and then proceed to further action

Comment: Thank you! I managed to get your previous code to work...Apparently I was rejected some of the promises...resolving the promise in any case would allow promise.all to work

Answer (score 2):

You can sequentially process any asychronous operations using following snippet:

```js
const log = console.log;
const currentTime = () => new Date().toLocaleTimeString();
const getData = waitFor => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, waitFor));

// Output:
//   Processing begin at 11:42:10
//   11:42:11 (1 second later)
//   11:42:13 (2 seconds later than previous)
//   11:42:16 (3 seconds later than previous)

log(`Processing begin at ${currentTime()}`);

[
    () => getData(1000).then(() => log(`${currentTime()} (1 second later)`)),
    () => getData(2000).then(() => log(`${currentTime()} (2 seconds later than previous)`)),
    () => getData(3000).then(() => log(`${currentTime()} (3 seconds later than previous)`)),
].reduce((promise, func) => promise.then(func), Promise.resolve());
```

Simply change function passed to `.then()` to something you want to process sequentially (like requests to YouTube API).

Then, you can further improve your code to get throttled requests to YouTube API:

```js
const throttle = (ms = 1000) => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
const getData = (channelId) => console.log(`${new Date().toLocaleTimeString()} - Downloaded data for channelId: ${channelId}`);

const channelIds = [1, 2, 3];

// Output:
//   Processing begin at 11:59:38
//   11:59:39 - Downloaded data for channelId: 1
//   11:59:40 - Downloaded data for channelId: 2
//   11:59:41 - Downloaded data for channelId: 3

console.log(`Processing begin at ${new Date().toLocaleTimeString()}`);

channelIds
  .map(channelId => () => throttle().then(() => getData(channelId)))
  .reduce((promise, func) => promise.then(func), Promise.resolve());
```

For more information on using promises check [MDN - Using promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises).